# New style is not applied to element on event

Tags: javascript, raphael

I generate some squares dynamically using rahaeljs. These squares have an event handler. When I try to manipulate the style, it fails depending on the attr() I try to set:

```
  function changeColor(obj) { 
      return function() { 
          obj.attr({cursor : 'pointer'}); 
      } 
  } 



   var main = function () {

    var width = 901;
    var height = 868;
    var space = 50;

    var paper = Raphael('paper', width, height);


    for (var y = 0; y < height; y += space) { 
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x += space) { 
            var r = paper.rect(x, y, space, space);
            r.attr({fill : 'transparent'})
            r.click(changeColor(r));


          } 
     } 

    };

    window.onload = main;
```

If I set the cursor to {cursor : 'pointer'}, this works fine, if I try to change the fill color with obj.attr({fill : '#ff00ff'}); in the changeColor-function, nothing happens. There is also no Error in the console.

I'm using the latest version of raphael.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
michael

Comment: do you want `fill` or `backgroundColor`

Comment: I don't care. I simply want to change the color on the display. I tried to use backgroundColor, but this doesn't change the colour aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be either very amused or very frustrated by this answer...  the problem has to do with the transparent fill attribute.  SVG treats fully transparent objects as unclickable, letting click events filter down to the layer(s) beneath them.  Therefore, your rectangles are not receiving click events.

If you can't set the color to a solid color, you can at least give the fill attribute a tiny, almost unnoticeable amount of alpha:

```
r.attr({ fill: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.001)' } );
```

That done, you should be back in business!

Comment: Hi, it's pure frustration. I tried your solution approach, but I'm still not back in business. The issue remains the same. What I don't understand in your argumentation: If a transparent object is unclickable, why the cursor-thing works? I tried with backgroundColor and fill. And I would prefer fill, but both doesn't change the color, only the cursor...

Comment: Ok, I got it, Thanks! Opacity 0.001 is still too transparent. if I set it to 0.5, it works... Nevertheless, I don't understand, why the cursor thing worked with a transparent object.

Comment: Curious -- 0.001 worked for me in Firefox.  I would still argue that using a solid fill is probably a wiser approach -- would that be feasible for you?

Comment: Now it works for me in Chorme as well. If I use fill:'blue', the opacity remains as it was. Therefore, the color change was not visible I think. I can't use a solid fill, since it's important, to see the background image of the div the paper is rendered in. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same behavior -- I believe specifying an rgba value for fill actually (correctly) sets fill-opacity, so if you subsequently use a simple solid fill, the low fill-opacity remains in effect.  Annoying.  Anyway: good luck!